# Message deformed from C to node JS via socket

Tags: javascript, c++, sockets

I wrote a C++ program that sends a message to a node js server.

```
string message;
int iResult = send( socket, message.c_str(), (int)strlen(message.c_str()), 0 );
```

The node JS code

```
net.createServer(function(sock) {

    // Add a 'data' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('data', function(data) {

        console.log(data);

    });

    // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
    });

}).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

The node JS server receives the message, but when I console.log the message received I get something like

```
<Buffer 31 7c 31 34>
```

What could be the problem and how can I fix this?

Comment: what are you sending?

Comment: I'm seding a `char *` . The message from C++ looks something like '2|23'. Basically, only 4-5 chars separated by a `|`.

Comment: isn't that what's in the buffer?

Comment: I don't know. But how do I convert something like `<Buffer 31 7c 31 34>` to my original string in javscript?

Comment: "31 7c 31 34".split(" ").map(function(a){return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a, 16));}) == ["1", "|", "1", "4"], but buffer has a toString() as well i thought... so, console.log(String(data)) i guess...

Comment: I tried to do `var strs = data.split(" ").map(function(a){return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a, 16));})`  but I get `TypeError: Object 1|11 has no method 'split'`.  `1|11` is the message I was sending from C++

Comment: `strlen(message.c_str())` because `message.size()` would be too efficient? (don't tell me it's because `message` might contain null characters, wherever it comes from you should have sanitized it the moment you got the input)

Comment: yeah, sorry for the irrelevant info, thinkning outloud in chrome's console. all you need is String(data), and i think you're good.

Comment: @dandavis Yes, it works. Could you please write it as an answer so I can accept it? thank you.